# How to solve unknown column 'x.y' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql, netbeans

I'm getting the following error when running this query on my MySQL database through Netbeans "execute query" ability.

```
Error code 1054, SQL state 42S22: Unknown column 'avgratingbyusers.avgrating' in 'field list'
Line 1, column 1

Execution finished after 0 s, 1 error(s) occurred.
```

From this code
Tutorial source: http://webdam.inria.fr/Jorge/html/wdmch19.html#x25-37800018.4

```
create table ratings ( 
   userid int, 
   itemid int, 
   rating int, 
   timestamp int, 
   primary key (userid, itemid)); 
create index usersratings_index on ratings (userid); 
create index itemsratings_index on ratings (itemid); 

insert into ratings (userid,itemid,rating,timestamp) 
   (select ratingsdata.userid, ratingsdata.itemid, 
        ratingsdata.rating-avgratingbyusers.avgrating, 
        ratingsdata.timestamp 
    from ratingsdata, 
       (select userid, avg(rating) 
        from ratingsdata 
        group by userid 
       ) as avgratingbyusers 
    where ratingsdata.userid=avgratingbyusers.userid 
   );
```

How do I go about fixing this?

Edit--------------------------------------------------

Attempted to change query to this

```
insert into `ratings` (`userid`,`itemid`,`rating`,`timestamp`) 
 (select `ratingsdata.userid`, `ratingsdata.itemid`, 
    `ratingsdata.rating-avgratingbyusers.avgrating`, 
    `ratingsdata.timestamp `
 from `ratingsdata`, 
   (select `userid`, avg(`rating`) 
    from `ratingsdata`
    group by `userid` 
   ) as `avgratingbyusers`
where `ratingsdata.userid`=`avgratingbyusers.userid`
);
```

with back ticks.

Now getting the following error

```
Error code 1054, SQL state 42S22: Unknown column 'ratingsdata.userid' in 'field list'
Line 1, column 1

Execution finished after 0 s, 1 error(s) occurred.
```

How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: You can probably erase the part you added with the backticks; that's not the correct use of backticks and is not the issue anyway.  The problem is that you're attempting to refer to `avgratingbyusers` within the first subselect, but `avgratingbyusers` does not exist at that level.  It exists only at the level of the outer select.  You probably want to move the subtraction you're trying to do into the outer select instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give columns in subqueries aliases:

```
insert into ratings (userid,itemid,rating,timestamp) 
   select rd.userid, rd.itemid, rd.rating-ru.avgrating, rd.timestamp 
    from ratingsdata rd join
         (select userid, avg(rating) as avgrating
----------------------------------------^
          from ratingsdata 
          group by userid 
         ) ru 
         on rd.userid = ru.userid ;
```

The important change is the one highlighted.  I made other changes:

- Removed the parentheses around the `select` clause.  These are unnecessary for an `insert . . . select`.
- Changed the join to use explicit joins instead of implicit joins.
- Introduced table aliases that are abbreviations of the table names, to make the query more readable.

Comment: I'm still getting a syntax error pointing towards the last two lines.

Comment: I removed the last parenthesis and changed the "on r.userid" to "on rd.userid". Seems to have worked. Thanks for the assist

Answer (score 0):

It seems the subtraction is impossible here, you might try to create a avgratingbyusers table first before running the codes;

## create avgratingbyusers

```
create table avgratingbyusers ( 
   userid int, 
   averating float); 

insert into avgratingbyusers (userid,averating) 
    (select userid, round(avg(rating),4) 
        from ratingsdata 
        group by userid);
```

## The centering is obtained by the following query:

```
create table ratings ( 
   userid int, 
   itemid int, 
   rating int, 
   timestamp int, 
   primary key (userid, itemid)); 
create index usersratings_index on ratings (userid); 
create index itemsratings_index on ratings (itemid); 

insert into ratings (userid,itemid,rating,timestamp) 
   (select ratingsdata.userid, ratingsdata.itemid, ratingsdata.rating-avgratingbyusers.averating, ratingsdata.timestamp 
    from ratingsdata, avgratingbyusers
    where ratingsdata.userid=avgratingbyusers.userid 
   );
```